# Kentico 9, IE error with cms:SearchBox

Tags: kentico

When a user clicks the submit button in IE, we're getting this:

> 'ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_search_btnSearch' is undefined

Chrome is fine, and pressing enter works.

I can't see anything strange with my code either:

```html
<cms:SearchBox
    ID="search"
    SearchTextboxCssClass="searchTextbox"
    ShowImageButton="false"
    SearchButtonCssClass="searchButton"
    SearchResultsPageUrl="~/Search-Results.aspx"
    PredictiveSearchEnabled="false"
    PredictiveSearchResultsCssClass="pSearch"
    PredictiveSearchMinCharacters="2"
    PredictiveSearchMaxResults="10"
    PredictiveSearchOptions="BasicSearch"
    PredictiveSearchMode="ExactPhrase"
    PredictiveSearchSort="##SCORE##"
    PredictiveSearchEnableSelection="true"
    PredictiveSearchIndexes="KFF-Global-PagesCrawler"
    ShowSearchLabel="False"
    SearchMode="ExactPhrase"
    runat="server" />
</div>
```

I'm not changing anything with the code behind either. I've tried a rebuild too.

Comment: To add another twist. Edge is fine, IE11 gives the error.

Comment: Only a shot in the dark, but it could be that for some reason IE11 is not identifying the ID properly when it posts back to the server.  When a page posts back on .Net, it includes the form values for the various elements that are applicable.  Can you inspect the request of the page after hitting enter for both IE and Chrome and see if you can see a difference in the values submitted in the post?